# Why my code which uses a logical expression as a case label throws error?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
switch(at){
case (at>0 && at<5) :
        printf("Average Time Taken (Hrs)\n%d.0",at);
        printf("Your Salary is Rs.%d",pj*1500 + 5000);
        break;
```

rest of the codes are similar. And i'm getting error for this `case (at>0 && at<5) :`

Comment: for what to use instead: an `if` statement.

Comment: @StoryTeller it is not possible but it actually makes sense, since it would be a nice feature if we could have expressions inside the switch.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki - We can only have expressions in the case. They just must be constant expressions. And even if this *was* a constant expression, its value is 1 or 0 (logical operators after all).

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki then it defeats the purpose. Switch case would then generate code exactly like a if-elseif-else ladder. On the other hand switch case with just const expressions allows for jump tables and other optimizations.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki what for? C has a somewhat tight relationship to the produced code and having a value compared to a set of constants can be compiled to quite different code (more efficient) than evaluating boolean expressions.

Comment: `case` expressions are compile-time integers. Yours is not. Compilation errors are *printed*, not 'thrown'. Exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.4.2

> The expression of each `case` label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of
>   the case constant expressions in the same `switch` statement shall have the same value
>   after conversion. [....]

so the `case` label expression cannot be a runtime-generated value dependent.

You can, use a fall-through syntax to achieve what you want, something like

```
switch(at){
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
        printf("Average Time Taken (Hrs)\n%d.0",at);
        printf("Your Salary is Rs.%d",pj*1500 + 5000);
        break;

  //some other case
```

Otherwise, if you're ok with using `gcc` extension, you can use **[*case-range* syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html)**, something like

```
switch(at){
case 1 ... 4:
        printf("Average Time Taken (Hrs)\n%d.0",at);
        printf("Your Salary is Rs.%d",pj*1500 + 5000);
        break;
```

Answer (score 3):

The case value in a switch statement must be a compile time constant (such as a literal, or a static const, or a #define to one of those).  For what you are trying to do, you need an `else if` chain:

```
if (0 < at && at < 5) {
    printf("Average Time Taken (Hrs)\n%d.0",at);
    printf("Your Salary is Rs.%d",pj*1500 + 5000);
} else if (5 <= at && at < 10) {
    // Your code here
```

Note that I have reversed the arguments to the first comparison (and the direction).  If you have multiple comparisons of the same variable, I find it much easier to read if they are all in the same direction.