# Why exactly can't we use relational expressions in a switch statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement, relational-operators

Since, there is no `true` `false` boolean type in C, what does the expression `x == y` evaluate to, when it's true and when it's false?

If it evaluates to 1 and 0 respectively, which are integers, why can't we use such expressions as `case`s for a `switch` statement?

Is the correct reason behind this:

1. case allows only integer expressions or expressions that evaluate to integers and x == y wouldn't evaluate to an integer (which I don't see how)? or
2. if switch allowed such expressions as cases there is a good chance that mutiple cases will end up having the same value, i.e., whenever `x==y`, we'll get a 1, so multiple such cases will evaluate to 1, or 0; which can't be allowed in switch statements.

Comment: Could you please show us an example of the code that you think ought to work, but doesn't? I have a guess at what your problem is, but I'm not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44627515/1216776

Comment: But you can use such an expression in a case label. `1 == 1` is an acceptable integer constant expression.

Comment: A `case` label must be a *constant expression*, meaning its value must be known *at compile time*.  If the values of `x` and `y` are not known until runtime, then `x == y` is not a constant expression, and thus cannot be used as part of a `case` label.

Comment: It is not sufficient to have them known at compile time, the expression must be a so-called **integer constant expression**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is not the **type** of `x==y`, but the fact that `case` takes a constant. `x==y` is usually not a constant.

Comment: but won't it evaluate to a constant? what does x == y evaluate to? doesn't it evaluate to `1` if true and `0` if false?

Comment: `x` and `y` values could change, so the result is not a constant.

Comment: @computronium: If `#define x 1` and `#define y 1` then it **does** evaluate to a constant. That's why I wrote _usually_ not a constant. There are exceptions. Note that `==`  is not special. `x+y` is usually not a constant either, for the same reason.